# How do you remove and return an item at the index of the queue for Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do you remove and return an item at the index of the queue for Python? I'm trying to do this problem.

When you send a file to be printed on a shared printer, it is put onto a print queue with other jobs. Anytime before your job prints, you can access the queue to remove it. Thus, some queues support a remove operation. The remove() method should expect an item as an argument. It should remove the given item in the queue or raise an exception if the item is not found.

```
class Queue:
    
    def __init__(self): # Constructor function
        self.items = []
    def isEmpty(self): # Returns True if the queue is empty or False otherwise
        return self.items == []
    def len(self): # Returns the number of items in the queue
        return len(self.items)
    def peek(self): # Returns the item at the front of the queue
        if len(self.items) == 0:
            return None 
        else: 
            return self.items[(len(self.items)-1)]
    def add(self, item): # Adds item to the rear of the queue
        return self.items.append(item)
    def pop(self): # Removes and returns the item at the front of the queue
        return self.items.pop()
    def remove(self):
         return.self.index.pop()
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    queue = Queue()
```

Comment: Well, `items` is a list, and lists have a `remove` method. Why don't you use that?

Comment: When I try to implement the remove method, I get the error 'Queue' object has no attribute 'remove'

Comment: What is `return.self.index.pop()` supposed to do. Syntax error.

Comment: I am trying to remove and return the item at index using .pop() but I'm not sure how to format it

Answer (score 0):

To remove an item you can use:

```
def remove(self, item):
     return self.items.remove(item)
```

which will generate a ValueError if item is not in the items List. If required you could use a `try: except:`  block to handle the error in some other way.